# Jquery validation for disabled selectbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

I am using jQuery validation for my application.I have a form that having 2 select boxes.The second select box is disabled according to the first select box value. Also these boxes are coming under an add more functionality. So the form may have multiple such boxes. Thus I am added the validation rules using addClassRules. example code is below.

```
  $.validator.addClassRules("classname", { required: true});
```

The validation working fine. I want to remove the validation for second dropdown when the first dropdown having a specific value. Currently I have the following issue

1. once the validation works
2. change the dropdown value
3. second box disabled.
4. click on the second dropdown and then click on out side the error message displayed for second dropdwon.
5. Form will submit when click on submit button.

I have tried with `$('form').validate({ignore:":disabled"});` inside first dropdown's onchange function. but it is not working.

I hope will get a solution for this problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can provide us a fiddle with your code ?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I have been added a new method using .addMethod and take the value of first dropdown inside that function . According to this value I applied validations criteria. Now its working fine. Thanks